# Checkout remote branch using git svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I have checked out a svn repository using git svn. Now I need to checkout one of the branches and track it. Which is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 368, accepted):

### Standard Subversion layout

Create a git clone of that includes your Subversion trunk, tags, and branches with

```
git svn clone http://svn.example.com/project -T trunk -b branches -t tags
```

The `--stdlayout` option is a nice shortcut if your Subversion repository uses the typical structure:

```
git svn clone http://svn.example.com/project --stdlayout
```

Make your git repository ignore everything the subversion repo does:

```
git svn show-ignore >> .git/info/exclude
```

You should now be able to see all the Subversion branches on the git side:

```
git branch -r
```

Say the name of the branch in Subversion is `waldo`. On the git side, you'd run

```
git checkout -b waldo-svn remotes/waldo
```

The -svn suffix is to avoid warnings of the form

```
warning: refname 'waldo' is ambiguous.
```

To update the git branch `waldo-svn`, run

```
git checkout waldo-svn
git svn rebase
```

---

### Starting from a trunk-only checkout

To add a Subversion branch to a trunk-only clone, modify your git repository's `.git/config` to contain

```
[svn-remote "svn-mybranch"]
        url = http://svn.example.com/project/branches/mybranch
        fetch = :refs/remotes/mybranch
```

You'll need to develop the habit of running

```
git svn fetch --fetch-all
```

to update all of what `git svn` thinks are separate remotes. At this point, you can create and track branches as above. For example, to create a git branch that corresponds to mybranch, run

```
git checkout -b mybranch-svn remotes/mybranch
```

For the branches from which you intend to `git svn dcommit`, keep their histories linear!

---

### Further information

You may also be interested in reading an [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140356/working-in-sync-with-svn-upstream/3220481#3220481).

Comment: This doesn't work for me, as I have checked out the trunk using git svn clone.. I didn't set branches to be checked out... I think I need to to that firstly.

Comment: The fact is that I used 
git svn clone http://svn.example.com/project/trunk

And now I don't know how to set other branches to be tracked without loosing my current repo...

Comment: I would suggest providing a prefix for your svn remotes. (add `--prefix=svn/` when doing `git-svn init` or `git-svn clone`)

This will eliminate the need to add a suffix on your local branches.

Comment: If you have several branches don't forget to do "git checkout master" before taking care of an other branche

Comment: If the `show-ignore` errors out, try `git svn show-ignore -i trunk`

Comment: Also note that even if you use the `--prefix=svn/`, so that your remote branch is called `remotes/svn/my-branch`, the shorter `git checkout -b my-branch` variant will not be able to automatically find & use the remote branch. It's probably due to that `git svn` doesn't write any `[remote "<name>"]` etc. into the `.git/config` file.

Comment: What should be used in place of `http://svn.example.com/project` if the repository is stored on an NFS share, e.g. at `\\MyServer\Share\Project`?