# git-svn, trunk-only checkout and remote branch that contains a hash mark in name

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm using a trunk-only checkout of a Subversion repository with non-standard layout. I need to checkout a remote branch to work on an issue. The branch has the name `#4711` at `branches/issues/#4711`. I am trying to use the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3240146/589206):

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://example.com/repos/projectname/trunk/sources
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
[svn-remote "svn-issue-4711"]
    url = https://example.com/repos/projectname/branches/issues/#4711
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn-issues-#4711
```

Unfortunately I get an error message:

```
W: Filesystem has no item: '/repos/projectname/!svn/rvr/6221/branches/issues' path not found at /usr/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 153.
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: '/repos/projectname/!svn/rvr/600/branches/issues' path not found
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
```

It seems the parser aborts at the hash mark, so I also tried to use some escaping, for example `\#4711` or `&234711` or `&0434711`, but these yield the error as well. What can I do to checkout this branch using `git-svn`? How to escape the branch name properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

```
[svn-remote "svn-issue-4711"]
    url = "https://example.com/repos/projectname/branches/issues/#4711"
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn-issues-4711
```

I'm leaving the whole thing for documentation purposes if anyone else has this problem.